# What's the best way to update a Map/Dictionary which is part of a MongoDb document?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, nosql

I'm new to MongoDb so I'm not sure what's the best approach regarding the following:

- I have a MongoDb document which contains multiple fields, including a map/dictionary.
  e.g. -> priceHistogram:

```
rents {
_id:"1234",
city:"London",
currentPrice:"500",
priceHistogram: {"14-02-2021" : "500"}
}
```

- I would like to update the currentPrice field with the latest price but also add to the price histogram taday's date and the price'; e.g. if today's price would be 600, I would like to obtain the following:

```
rents {
_id:"1234",
city:"London",
currentPrice:"600",
priceHistogram: {"14-02-2021" : "500", "20-02-2021" ": "600"}
}
```

What would be the most efficient MongoDb function/approach allowing me to achieve this (everything else remains the same - _id/city)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your schema looks like, I will assume that the schema looks similar to:

```
    const rentsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
        {
            city: { type: String, required: true },
            currentPrice: {type: String},
            priceHistogram: {type: Map, of:String}
        }
    )
    const rents = mongoose.model('Rents', histSchema);
```

And the update:

```
rents.updateOne({city:"London"},{
        currentPrice:"600",
        "priceHistogram.24-02-2021":  "600"
    })
```

Since as I have understood  Map is another way to add arbitrary properties.